# Spring boot auto-configuration and properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I have 2 modules in my project app & starter. Starter contains `@Configuration` and tells how a bean of `ServiceFoo` should be created.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FooServiceConfiguration.class)
public class StarterFoo {

    @Bean
    public ServiceFoo defaultBean(FooServiceConfiguration conf){
      new ServiceFooImpl(conf.getName(), conf.getNumber());
    }

}
```

I have another configuration class in my starter.

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties("Foo")
public class FooServiceConfiguration {
    private String name;
    private int number;
    // + accessors
}
```

in my starter I have `application.yml` which has

```
Foo:
 name: DefaultName
 number: 101
```

starter is configured to be auto-configured

META-INF/spring.factories

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=StarterFoo
```

I want to have opinion on my config about number and user will never worry and override that number. I want users to override name in my config.

As soon as I create application.yml in app (blank file) the effect of starter's config (from application.yml from starter) goes away.

How can I partially override this config from app which is defined in starter ?

Comment: it's not clear, if `application.yml` id blank the your application will log and error saying server startup failed

Comment: blank `application.yml` is accepted. why do you think it will fail ? @Deadpool

Comment: okay may because you are not using `@Value` annotation to inject properties, okay when it is blank what are the values for `private String name;` and
    `private int number;` ?

Comment: @ConfigurationProperties is expected to bind.

Answer (score 1):

There can only be a single Boot configuration file with a specific name regardless of where on the classpath they're located (i.e., you can have `application-test.yml` and `application.yml`, but only one of each), and "closer" to runtime (the fat jar) overrides more distant (embedded jars). Boot doesn't merge the contents, it simply only reads a single `application.yml`.

The simplest way to accomplish what you want is to use Java normally and initialize the class variables with your default values:

```
private String name = "DefaultName";
private int number = 101;
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes hardcoding default is an option. How do I read it from config if not `application.yml` may be `foo.yml` for that particular `foo` starter ?

Comment: The usecase is I want to control some third party starters within my org and provide wrapper starter around it. Those wrapper should be external starter + my config

Comment: @user3833308 That use case is very tricky to handle cleanly. The least-complicated option is probably to use a special profile and supply the `application-profile.yml`.

Comment: That will do the trick. Thanks Chrylis, Basically I have a starter where I want to configure the embedded tomcat's configuration. If you know of any other way please share

Comment: @user3833308 It really depends on the organizational setup; for example, unless you can control the specifics of the Boot configuration in the end projects it's not even a given that Tomcat will be used (I prefer Undertow).

Comment: sure I have control of org setup. what is the preferred way to control these ?

Comment: @user3833308 You just have an organizational policy that says "all of our Boot Web projects use Tomcat".

Comment: I have a starter that everybody will use in org. that starter has to control configuration of tomcat. every app will include the base starter